# Add Text After the Price in WooCommerce Product Per Product ID/WP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code in my child theme's functions.php file, and it works great.

```
function themeprefix_custom_price_message( $price ) { 

global $post;

$product_id = $post->ID;
$my_product_array = array( 270,373,378,506,1306,1311,1312,1444,1445,1447,1449,1930,1932,1933,1934,1935,1963,4146,4152,4153,4154 );//add in product IDs
if ( in_array( $product_id, $my_product_array )) {
    $textafter = ' Each/Min 12'; //add your text
    return $price . '<span class="price-description">' . $textafter . '</span>';
 } 
 else 
 { 
    return $price; 
 } 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'themeprefix_custom_price_message' );
```

However, now I need to add another group of products and enable different text after the price, i.e., Each/Min 8. I have tried various changes to the above and have brought the site down each time. How do I adjust the above to add another (and then possibly another) group of product IDs with different text after the price? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leave the existing array as it is. Simplify the code by removing the `else` from the `if` and then start declaring & checking new product arrays before returning the default price-only text...

```
function themeprefix_custom_price_message( $price ) { 

    global $post;

    $product_id = $post->ID;

    $my_product_array = array( 270,373,378,506,1306,1311,1312,1444,1445,1447,1449,1930,1932,1933,1934,1935,1963,4146,4152,4153,4154 );//add in product IDs

    if ( in_array( $product_id, $my_product_array )) {
        $textafter = ' Each/Min 12'; //add your text
        return $price . '<span class="price-description">' . $textafter . '</span>';
    } 

    $my_product_array2 = array( 9990,9991,9992 );

    if ( in_array( $product_id, $my_product_array2 )) {
        $textafter = ' Each/Min 8'; //add your text
        return $price . '<span class="price-description">' . $textafter . '</span>';
    }

    $my_product_array3 = array( 9993,9994,9995 );

    if ( in_array( $product_id, $my_product_array3 )) {
        $textafter = ' Each/Min 4'; //add your text
        return $price . '<span class="price-description">' . $textafter . '</span>';
    }

    return $price;  
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'themeprefix_custom_price_message' );
```

Comment: Thank you @davmos That works great! I sincerely appreciate the help!

Comment: You're very welcome, Patricia, glad to hear it works :)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for the question which was asked here: [Add custom text after the price in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213835/add-custom-text-after-the-price-in-woocommerce)

However, it can also be used in the above question.

You can try something like that if you want dynamic text after every product.

```
/* add custom field in single product */

add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', function() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input([
            'id' => '_custom_text_after_price',
            'label' => __('Custom Text after Price', 'themedomain'),
    ]);
});
```

You can see the above changes in your product.

[image]

Now add the below code to save meta in your product

```
/* save meta field */
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
{
    $woocommerce_custom_product_text_field = $_POST['_custom_text_after_price'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_text_after_price', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_text_field));
}
```

And now to display custom code on the front end you need to use 2 hooks.

```
/* show custom text on front end */
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    global $post, $product;
    if(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_text_after_price', true )){
        $text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_text_after_price', true );
    }
    $price .= ' '.$text;
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
```

In the front end, it will look like this.

[image]